# Would you use a type class in this case?

Tags: scala, polymorphism, typeclass

Suppose I've got an ADT like this:

```
sealed trait A extends Product with Serializable
object A {
  case class A1() extends A
  case class A2() extends A
  case class A3() extends A
  case class A4() extends A
}
```

Suppose also I have a `trait AFoo` like that:

```
type Foo = ...
trait AFoo { def asFoo(a: A): Foo }
```

Now I need to provide two different implementations for `AFoo`. So I am writing something like that:

```
abstract class AFooSupport extends AFoo {

  protected def asFoo1(a1: A1): Foo
  protected def asFoo2(a2: A2): Foo
  protected def asFoo3(a3: A3): Foo
  protected def asFoo4(a4: A4): Foo

  def asFoo(a: A) = a match {
    case a1: A1 => asFoo1(a1)
    case a2: A2 => asFoo2(a2)
    case a3: A3 => asFoo3(a3)
    case a4: A4 => asFoo4(a4)
  }
} 

class AFoo1 extends AFooSupport { 
  // implement asFoo1, asFoo2, asFoo3, asFoo4
}

class AFoo2 extends AFooSupport { 
  // implement asFoo1, asFoo2, asFoo3, asFoo4
}
```

This approach will probably work but I wonder if there is a better way to do it. Would you use a *type class* in this case ?

Comment: Do you actually need multiple implementations of `asFoo`? Using a type class for an operation that only applies to a single ADT seems odd. If you really want to abstract out the matching, a fold seems more reasonable.

Comment: I need only one implementation of `asFoo`. Will try the `fold`, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one function `(A => Foo)` for concrete classes with different implementations. I don't see here big advantage of using a type class. I would start considering a type class when one of arguments is generic.

As suggested in comments one could extract pattern matching into fold

```
def fold[F](a: A)(f1: A1 => F, ..., f4: A4 => F): F = a match {
    case a1: A1 => f1(a1)
    ...
}
```

and implement required functions:

```
def aFoo(a: A): Foo = fold(a)(afoo1, afoo2, afoo3, afoo4)
def afoo1(a: A1): Foo = ... 
...
def afoo4(a: A4): Foo = ...

def bFoo(a: A): Foo = fold(a)(bfoo1, bfoo2, bfoo3, bfoo4)
...
def bfoo4(a: A4): Foo = ...
```

But your `AFooSupport` is already sort of a fold implemented using inheritance instead of composition.

Comment: Note that for the `fold`, each argument function doesn't need to take `A1`, etc. as arguments—`A1`, etc. have no members, so the arguments to fold would be `(f1: => F, f2: => F, ...)`.

Answer (score -2):

On the first look it seems like you could use generics as a Solution or solve your problem with inheritance.